# Ionic 4 facebook login issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Native Facebook login in my app and its working fine but don't know why from few days its stop working and showing the error

```
Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later
```

Anyone know what is this error? I already try to remove the catch data and clear storage of the app.

Comment: Please post details amd full error log. There can be many reasons for failed login.

Comment: @PankajSati there is not error showing in console just this error showing only